# Finding probability using Chebyshev's Theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

> Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be i.i.d random variables. $X_i$ ~ $Unif(-1,1)$
>
> Let $Y_1,...,Y_n$ be i.i.d random variables. $~~$$Y_i$ ~ $Unif(-1,1)$
>
> Let us define a new random variable $Z_i$. $Z_i=1$ if $(X_i,Y_i)$ lies within the unit-disk. And $Z_i=0$ if $(X_i,Y_i)$ lies outside the unit disk.
>
> . What is the mean and variance of $\bar{Z_n}$? What about $4\bar{Z_n}$?
>
> . Is $4\bar{Z_n}$ close to $\pi$? Find $P(|4\bar{Z_9}-\pi|>.01)$. Use Chebyshev's theorem to find bound on this probability. What about $P(|4\bar{Z}_{100}-\pi|>.01)$?
>
> . Instead of finding a bound as in the last example, find the $P(|4\bar{Z_9}-\pi|>.01)$ approximately using Central Limit Theorem.

I am having trouble using Chebyshev's theorem. I think my $Var(4\bar{Z}_{9})$ might be wrong but unsure why.

$$Z_i \sim Bern(\frac{\pi}{4})$$

$$E(\bar{Z_n})=\dfrac{\pi}{4} ,~ Var(\bar{Z_n})=(\dfrac{\pi}{4n}-\dfrac{\pi^2}{16n})$$

$$E(4\bar{Z_n})=\pi ,~ Var(4\bar{Z_n})=\dfrac{\pi}{n}(4-\pi)$$

Since $P(|X-E(x)|>k)\leq\dfrac{Var(X)}{k^2}$

$$P(|4\bar{Z_9}-\pi|>.01)\leq \dfrac{(4\pi - \pi^2)}{9(.01^2)}$$

But this number is clearly incorrect. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Why is it clearly incorrect? It looks correct.

Comment: the bound evaluates to almost 3000 @E-A. Does this matter?

Comment: No; it would be an issue if it were, say, negative. This is after all a "bound"; it does not need to be a good one. This bound will get better as n goes to infinity. (i.e. when you put n instead of 9)

Comment: Am I correct in saying $Z_i \sim Bern(\dfrac{\pi}{4})$ @E-A?

Comment: As always I would like to point out that independence assumptions are important in probability. This question has no answer unless $X_i$'s are independent of $Y_i$'s.

Comment: Yes, if $X_i$s and $Y_i$s are independent (see (important) comment above).

Comment: You can't find probabilities from Chebyshev's inequality. What you can find is a bound (and the problem asks you to find that).